# Find a decomposition of the given matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, svd

I have encountered a task, which I do not really know how to approach.

I need to find a decomposition

$$A = U\Sigma V^T$$

of the matrix:

$$
A =
\begin{pmatrix}
2&1&2&\\
-2&-1&-2&\\
4&2&4&\\
2&1&2&\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Where $\Sigma$ is a rect diagonal matrix of size 4 x 3, U and V are orthogonal matrices, and the upper right element of V is equal to $1\sqrt2$.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4042894/find-svd-of-the-given-matrix