# Find SVD of the given matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, svd, pseudoinverse

> Find a decomposition $X=U \Sigma V^{T}$ of the matrix $X=\begin{bmatrix}
> 2 & 1 & 2\\ 
> -2 & -1 & -2\\
> 4 & 2 & 4\\
> 2 & 1 & 2
> \end{bmatrix}$  where $\Sigma$ is a rectangular diagonal matrix of
> size 4x3, $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal matrices, and the upper right element of $V$ is equal to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

I found V according to the given constraint as $\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{2}{3} & \frac{-\sqrt{2}}{6} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
\frac{1}{3} & \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3} & 0\\
\frac{2}{3} & \frac{-\sqrt{2}}{6} & \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{bmatrix}$ and $\Sigma=\begin{bmatrix}
\sqrt{63} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

For finding $U$, I am using $U\Sigma=XV$. But I am stuck at this step as to how to proceed further as $\Sigma$ matrix has repeated 0 eigen values.

Can you please let me know how to find $U$ from the above equation?

Comment: You get the first column of $U$. The others just have to complete the first one to an orthonormal basis. You can get them for example by performing Gram-Schmidt.

Comment: @amsmath ok but from $U\Sigma=XV$ how to get the same?

Comment: It will be the same because $\Sigma$ has zeros in its second and third column.

Comment: @amsmath ok i got $XV=\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
-3 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
6 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
3 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$ but how to proceed from this step to find U?

Comment: The first column of $U$ is $\frac 1{\sqrt{63}}\begin{bmatrix}3\\-3\\6\\3\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: @amsmath Yes but for the rest of the columns if they are all 0, then U would not be an orthonormal matrix.

Comment: I told you what to do in my first comment. Can't you read?

Comment: @amsmath ok but would it be hit and trial then to get the orthonormal basis. How to apply Gram-Schmidt on the same as we have only first column vector of U?

Comment: Call your vector $u$. Then $\{u,e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ is a basis. Now, do Gram-Schmidt.

Comment: @amsmath got it thanks

Answer (score 0):

You already found the eigenvectors of $X^TX$. These are the rows of $V^T$.

You need to find the eigenvectors of $XX^T$. There should be one eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue of $\sqrt {63}$ and three corresponding to the zero eigenvalue. Arrange them as column vectors $U=\begin{pmatrix}u_1&u_2&u_3&u_4\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Thanks but from $U\Sigma=XV$ how to find the same?